# How to represent a set of values in a relational database

Tags: sql, database-design

Let's say I have a set of values of some category, for example sports activities.

The values might be:

1. Running
2. Basketball
3. Football
4. Ice Hockey
5. Walking
6. Baseball
7. Basketball

Now let's assume that I have a large group of individuals. Each person engages in a set of sports activities for each season of the year. So person A might play Basketball and Run in Winter, play baseball and run in Spring and Summer, and play Football and run in the fall. Person B might walk and run in the spring, fall, and summer and play basketball and ice hockey in the winter, etc.

In other words each person has 4 sets (or arrays) of sports activities (call them favorite spots activities) one for each season.

What I am trying to figure out is the best way to map these sets of values to individuals in a relational database efficiently. I assume I will have one table of people and one table of sports activities. But how do I represent overlapping sets of values from the sports activities table and map them to individual people in the people table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You map the activity to a person. Your table would reference the activity and person, and the primary key would be a composite of both those.

```
person <----- personActivity -----> activity
```

If you want to add in seasons:

```
person, activity, season

personActivitySeasn
```

Comment: But the same activity might be mapped multiple times if the person does the same activity in several different seasons.   I don't get how you represent this.

Comment: As suggested by FreshPrinceOfSO you can make composite key with three cols (person, activity, season) in third table.

Comment: @Elliott see [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebc16/1). You will need to set up foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

You would also have a table of seasons (probably with just four values).  Then you would have a table `PersonActivitySeasons` with columns like:

- PersonActivitySeasonId
- PersonId
- SeasonId
- ActivityId
- Date of Activity

This is the most normalized format.  In practice, you might also make the seasons columns:

- PersonActivitySeasonId
- PersonId
- ActivityId
- IsWinter
- IsSpring
- IsSummer
- IsAutumn

I would tend to go with the first approach, because I could include effective and end dates for each record for each season, and more easily track people going in and out of activities.  Also, it would allow for "non-conforming" seasons, if that were useful for you.

Comment: I would not suggest the second approach; even if there are only 4 seasons just because of the activity dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third table "Activities" containing Person id (PK in person table) and sport id (PK in Sport table).